# Question regarding two independent Poisson processess

Tags: poisson-distribution

Given two independent Poisson processes X and Y I am trying to calculate what the probability is of X ever, at any given point, has been above Y as time approaches infinity. ¨

As an example lets assume lambda 2 for X and 3 for Y, process Y starts at 4 and process X starts at 0. A real world illustration, we have two bridges X and Y, average frequency of cars passing per hour is 2 for bridge X and 3 for bridge Y. There have already passed 4 cars on bridge Y, what is the probability that given infinite time more cars at any given point drove over bridge X than bridge Y.

I, with the help of some others, came up with a function that describes this for any given time, however not for all time.

$P(X(t)>Y(t)+n)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg [P(X(t)+n\cap Y(t)=k) \bigg] \\
\\
\\
P(X(t)>Y(t)+n)=1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg [\underbrace{P(X(t)\leq k+n)}_{Poisson\: CDF}*\underbrace{P(Y(t)=k)}_{Poisson \: pmf} \bigg] \\$

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for quite some time.